# Checking if value is in a CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm wanting to sift through a csv file and check if a phrase exists (Pipe) in one of the columns. At the moment the alert box is popping up saying all different versions of variable code exists, which is incorrect.

Script to process the `CSV` file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Enterre');
    $('#load_data').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "assets/exports/pipe.csv",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                var code = "Test";
                // Remove \n and split by ,
                var pipeList = data.split('\n').map(function (row) {
                    return row.split(',')
                });
                // Array of arrays like be generated
                for (var i = 0; i < pipeList.length; i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(code, pipeList[i]) != -1) {
                        alert('value is in Array!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('value is not');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`CSV` file

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfq5Z.png)

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with a minimal code (with the .csv).

Comment: You need to split the CSV data by the line break character, ie. `[^\r\n]+`, then split each row by `,`. I would strongly suggest you use a full featured CSV parser though, otherwise you may encounter issues with quotes, or character encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion rory, i've changed my OP above. I'm getting an error stating pipeList.split is not a function now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this changed code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Enterre');
  $('#load_data').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "assets/exports/pipe.csv",

      success: function(data) {

        var code = "Pipe"; 
        // Flag that value found
        var found = false;
        // Remove \n and split by ,
        var pipeList = data.split('\n').map(function(row){return row.split(',')});
        // Array of arrays like be generated
          for(var i = 0; i < pipeList.length; i++){
              if ($.inArray(code, pipeList[i]) != -1) {          
                  found = true;
                  alert('value is Array!');
              }
          }
          if(!found){
            alert('value is not in Array');
          }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="load_data">Load</button>
```

Comment: thankyou for the suggestion, i've updated my OP with the code you are using+ a bit of my own. At the moment the else statement is always triggering regardless of what the variable code is.

Comment: Depends on your changes, my version is working only when there is **word** in the `CSV` that is given as a needle.

Comment: I see, i've included a snippet of my CSV file to showcase what i'm trying to match.